# Android web view hybrid app is not redirecting to payment gateway but the in website view it was redirecting to payment gateway

Tags: c#, android, payment-gateway, hybrid, payu

I created a website which is pointing to payu money gateway, It is working fine.
Then I created a webview android app for my website by redirecting my app to my website link but from app I am not able to open Payment gateway page.
Any Idea why it is not working from App webview whereas it was working from website view.

Comment: You should provide some code.

Comment: I made domstorage true and it started working fine.